# Is Go's concurrency model suitable for distributed systems and for microservices?

Tags: concurrency, go

In *Programming Distributed Computing Systems*:

> **7.3.4 Distribution**
>
> Distributed computing is inherently concurrent. However, distribution
> aspects go far beyond concurrency. Of particular importance from a
> modeling perspective is the capability to reason about the location
> (and potential co-location) of concurrent com- putations, the
> heterogeneous cost of interaction, the security aspects of interaction
> across multiple locations, and the potential for partial failures.
>
> The concurrent computing models that we have studied offer diverse
> levels of abstraction and therefore support reasoning about
> distributed computation to different degrees.
>
> In the π calculus, there is no explicit representation of locations.
> Processes can arbitrarily and uniformly interact with any other
> processes, as long as they share a channel name. Therefore, from a
> modeling perspective, it is not directly possible to distinguish
> between the interaction of two processes in the same processor and the
> interaction of two processes in two computers across two different
> continents. Therefore, in an executable realization of the π calculus,
> a channel abstraction may be implemented as a single machine register
> in the simplest case, or it may require a network socket
> implementation requiring the coordination of multiple servers for
> interprocess communication. Since channels are ﬁrst-class communicable
> entities and process communication topology is thus dynamic, this
> so-called process “mobility” may require signiﬁcantly expensive
> channel implementation strategies. Furthermore, truly synchronous
> communication is impossible to implement among processors in
> geographically distant computers.
>
> In the actor model, sequential computation is modeled using the λ
> calculus, making the distributed interaction between actors explicit
> through a network, mod- eled as a multiset of messages en route. The
> state encapsulation and asynchronous communication aspects of the
> actor model (see section 7.1) make it better suited to model and
> implement distributed computing systems. However, there is no explicit
> notion of actor location, and therefore, communication between actors
> in the same processor and actors across the planet is uniformly
> modeled.

If I am correct that

- Go has an implementation of pi calculus,
- Go is recommended  for distributed systems and for microservices

my questions are:

- Is it Go's implementation of pi calculus that is recommended   for distributed systems and for microservices ?
- If yes, why, given the quote saying pi calculus is not good for distributed computing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, Go's channels do not make it extra-well-suited for microservice architectures. It's a perfectly fine language for such tasks, but that's largely unrelated to its concurrency features.

In the Pi Calculus, we have processes and channels. Go has goroutines and channels, making it possible to take a computation that was modelled in Pi Calculus and to encode it as a Go program.

However, take a typical Go program and you will find something that is definitely not from the Pi Calculus. Goroutines can share data and communicate over variables, i.e. memory locations. This is explicitly out of scope for the Pi Calculus, and gives rise to all of the concurrency bugs that make multithreading in C so difficult.

In the article you're reading, the Pi Calculus is criticized for synchronous messaging, which is unsuitable for distributed computing. But Go's encoding of the Pi Calculus doesn't involve distribution, it just involves goroutines that run within the same process on the same computer. Also, Go's channels offer buffering.

When we do have a distributed system with multiple processes across multiple computers – such as in a microservice architecture – Go's channels are inapplicable. Communication between processes happens over the network instead, e.g. using UDP messages or TCP sockets, or using higher-level protocols such as Kafka or HTTP/REST. Go doee have some nice features here such as deeply integrated support for serialization, or the ability to easily listen on multiple sockets with a select statement.

In practice, you will find that any language with decent support for asynchronous operations will be a decent choice for microservices. E.g. C#, Python, JavaScript and Rust have very convenient async/await syntax, though Go's channels have a similar effect. Languages like Java or C++ also have good support for library-level event loops, just with less convenient syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I heard Go is used a lot in distributed systems. Am I wrong, given that Go's channels are inapplicable to that?

Comment: @Tim Go is widely used for implementing distributed systems (like Kubernetes!). But Go's language-level support for channels has very little to do with this. Other Go features (like memory safety, or easily building static binaries) are probably much more important. Go's channel are useful *within* a program, but don't support communication *between* computers, as would be the case in a distributed system.

Comment: thanks. what libraries in GO are used for distributed systems and for microservices? What concurrency models do the libraries provide? Is Go used for implementing a distributed system or programming on top of a distributed system or both?